# Can SharePoint 2010 support validateRequest="true"?

Tags: 2010, security, web-config

By default, web application web.configs have validateRequest="false". Changing it to true breaks SharePoint significantly, based on my own trials. People Pickers don't work, half the form pages don't work, etc.

This option, as I understand it, blocks any HTTP requests that contain any HTML. Which seems to be quite a lot of things in SharePoint.

Is there any work around to this? Or does SharePoint just not support this setting?

Comment: why you need to set validateRequest=“true”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same question. During a ethical security scan we where advised to enable this option. We tested what would happen if we enabled this option. Some list forms stopped working. For example because there was a rich html field present on the form.
We contacted Microsoft support about this and they told us that enabling this option in the web.config is unsupported.